# Redshift Spectrum table doesnt recognize array

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue, external-tables, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have ran a crawler on json S3 file for updating an existing external table.
Once finished I checked the SVL_S3LOG to see the structure of the external table and saw it was updated and I have new column with Array<int> type like expected.
When I have tried to execute select * on the external table I got this error: "Invalid operation: Nested tables do not support '*' in the SELECT clause.;"
So I have tried to detailed the select statement with all columns names:
select name, date, books.... (books is the Array<int> type)
from external_table_a1
and got this error:
Invalid operation: column "books" does not exist in external_table_a1;"
I have also checked under "AWS Glue" the table external_table_a1 and saw that column "books" is recognized and have the type Array<int>.
Can someone explain why my simple query is wrong?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Querying JSON data is a bit of a hassle with Redshift: when parsing is enabled (eg using the appropriate SerDe configuration) the JSON is stored as a SUPER type. In your case that's the `Array<int>`.

The [AWS documentation on Querying semistructured data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html) seems pretty straightforward, mentioning that PartiQL uses "dotted notation and array subscript for path navigation when accessing nested data". This doesn't work for me, although I don't find any reasons in their [SUPER Limitations Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/limitations-super.html).

#### Solution 1

What I have to do is set the flags `set json_serialization_enable to true;` and `set json_serialization_parse_nested_strings to true;` which will parse the SUPER type as JSON (ie back to JSON). I can then use [JSON-functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html) to query the data. Unnesting data gets even crazier because you can only use the [unnest syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html#unnest) `select item from table as t, t.items as item` on SUPER types. I genuinely don't think that this is the supposed way to query and unnest SUPER objects but that's the only approach that worked for me.

They described that in some older ["Amazon Redshift Developer Guide"](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-redshift-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/serializing-complex-JSON.md).

#### Solution 2

When you are writing your query or creating a query Redshift will try to fit the output into one of the basic column data types. If the result of your query does not match any of those types, Redshift will not process the query. Hence, in order to convert a SUPER to a compatible type you will have to unnest it (using the rather peculiar [Redshift unnest syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html#unnest)).

For me, this works in certain cases but I'm not always able to properly index arrays, nor can I access the array index (using `my_table.array_column as array_entry at array_index` syntax).

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me as well. Its crazy how its almost impossible to find this in the docs.

Comment: i have the same and your solution worked. However the column is appearing as `varchar`, is there a way to convert it to `super`?

Comment: @lollerskates I was only able to _access_ the `super` but not select a value that is not one of the basic data types. I always had to unnest the super until the resulting value is one of the basic data types.